# Alexa AMAZON.DATE slot default to past dates

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am using the `AMAZON.DATE` slot and I would like it to default to past dates.

For example, if a user says Monday I would like it to automatically select last Monday rather than next Monday.

In the documentation it confirms that it defaults to 'on or after the current date':

> "Utterances that map to a specific date (such as "today", "now", or
>   "november twenty-fifth") convert to a complete date: 2015-11-25. Note
>   that this defaults to dates on or after the current date (see below
>   for more examples)."

For my application there is no way a future date would make sense so it wouldn't be too difficult to manually program this in but I just wondered if there was any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change the behavior of built in slots, so if Alexa resolves user's answer as a date - before passing it to your further processing just subtract 7 from resolved value. It will give you the date in the past.

Comment: That only works for "Tuesday", not for "January 1st" -- without year specified, Amazon.Date always assumed it looks forward. And we don't get the original request text, so we can't distinguish these two cases. The user can kluge around this by always saying "last"; we can notice future dates and ask the user to confirm our guess or rephrase, but that's not great from a usability standpoint.